# Forcing Console to Skip Already-Guessed Characters in a Randomly Cycling Code-Guesser

Tags: c#, console-application

The code begins by asking how many digits a code is. It then creates a random string of letters as long as the answer, and begins cycling through characters until it finds the code. Each character that matches is kept in the same place until each character matches.

The issue is with the console continuously guessing the incorrect character, leading to situations where the console continues guessing the wrong character and never solving it.

So, I want the console to not try incorrect characters after guessing them already.

On a side note, if anyone has any ideas on how I could change the code to instead guess one character at a time, then continue to the next, please tell me, thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Random random = new Random();
        public static string RandomString(int length)
        {
            const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        }



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;


            string intro6 = "How many characters in the password? (USE INTEGERS)";
            foreach (char c in intro6)
            {
                Console.Write(c);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            string delta = Console.ReadLine();

            try
            {


                int passwordlength = Convert.ToInt32(delta);

                // BARRIER

                string password = RandomString(passwordlength);

                Random r = new Random();
                string letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                List<string> dictionary = new List<string>(new string[] {
            password
        });

                string word = dictionary[r.Next(dictionary.Count)];
                List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(letters[r.Next(letters.Length)]);
                    if (sb[i] != word[i])
                    {
                        indexes.Add(i);

                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

                while (indexes.Count > 0)
                {
                    int index;

                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                    Console.Clear();

                    for (int i = indexes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        index = indexes[i];
                        sb[index] = letters[r.Next(letters.Length)];
                        if (sb[index] == word[index])
                        {

                            indexes.RemoveAt(i);




                        }


                    }
                    var output = sb.ToString();

                    for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (indexes.Contains(i))
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                        }

                        Console.Write(output[i]);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();



                }

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

                string outro1 = "Password successfully breached. Have a nice day.";
                foreach (char c in outro1)
                {
                    Console.Write(c);
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Thread.Sleep(100);


                Console.ReadLine();

            }

            catch
            {


                if (delta is string)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("FATAL ERROR PRESS ENTER TO EXIT");


                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("welp, it was worth a try.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }




            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Judging by my testing, turns out the intermittent success was caused by the password having numbers but it only tries letters. So either remove numbers from `chars` or add them to `letters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wubbler mentioned in his comment, it appears that you have a discrepancy between the characters being used to create the random password and the characters then being used to guess the password.

To create:

```
const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
```

To guess:

```
string letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

This causes the program to be unable to guess the password when the randomly generated password contains any numbers. By adding the numbers to the guessable characters, the program then succeeds more consistently.

And as for the request:

> I want the console to not try incorrect characters after guessing them
>   already

You can achieve this by keeping a collection of guessable characters per index, and then removing a character from it's collection for the given index once it's guessed. The following code satisfies this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

    string intro6 = "How many characters in the password? (USE INTEGERS)";
    foreach (char c in intro6)
    {
        Console.Write(c);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
    string delta = Console.ReadLine();

    try
    {
        int passwordlength = Convert.ToInt32(delta);

        // BARRIER

        string password = RandomString(passwordlength);

        Random r = new Random();
        string letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        List<string> dictionary = new List<string>(new string[] { password });

        string word = dictionary[r.Next(dictionary.Count)];
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(letters[r.Next(letters.Length)]);
            if (sb[i] != word[i])
            {
                indexes.Add(i);

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

        var charsToGuessByIndex = indexes.ToDictionary(k => k, v => letters);

        while (indexes.Count > 0)
        {
            int index;

            Thread.Sleep(10);
            Console.Clear();

            for (int i = indexes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                index = indexes[i];

                var charsToGuess = charsToGuessByIndex[index];
                sb[index] = charsToGuess[r.Next(charsToGuess.Length)];
                charsToGuessByIndex[index] = charsToGuess.Remove(charsToGuess.IndexOf(sb[index]), 1);
                if (sb[index] == word[index])
                {
                    indexes.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
            var output = sb.ToString();

            for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
            {
                if (indexes.Contains(i))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                }

                Console.Write(output[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

        string outro1 = "Password successfully breached. Have a nice day.";
        foreach (char c in outro1)
        {
            Console.Write(c);
            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch
    {
        if (delta is string)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("FATAL ERROR PRESS ENTER TO EXIT");


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("welp, it was worth a try.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The `charsToGuessByIndex` keeps track of which characters can be guessed per index, and is updated accordingly inside the for loop where characters are guessed at:

```
charsToGuessByIndex[index] = charsToGuess.Remove(charsToGuess.IndexOf(sb[index]), 1);
```